# How to hide a DataGridColumn by using DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I have a WPF DataGrid in which I define my columns manually. Depending on a property in my ViewModel I'd like to show/hide a DataGridComboboxColumn by using a DataTrigger.

Unfortunately DataGridColumn and DataGridComboBoxColumn do not have a Style property that I could use for this. Is there any way to achieve the show/hide functionality by using a DataTrigger or do I only have the possibility set a binding directly to the Visibility Property of the DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475212/wpf-datatrigger-to-display-and-hide-grid-column-xaml) is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hide this by the Property you can use the Data trigger by defining the cell template. In that we can add the data triggers within the data template.

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterCellStyle}" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <Label  Content="Header 1  " Foreground="White"  />
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate  >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,0,0,0">
                    <Image Margin="2">
                        <Image.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ANSWER}" Value="Yes">
                                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ANSWER}" Value="No">
                                         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Resources>
                    </Image>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here,showing datagrid for Hide the item (Image) by using the data trigger .
try the same for hide the combo box in the cell template.
Hope it works.